# AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `files` on serializer `FilesSerializer`

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm uploading multiple files from my vue front to my drf backend.
While the files DO get sent and posted (thanks to someone here btw ), this error keeps popping :

AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `files` on serializer `FilesSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `list` instance.
Original exception text was: 'list' object has no attribute 'files'.

**views.py**

```
class FileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    parser_classes = (FormParser,MultiPartParser)
    queryset = File.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FileSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
    class FilesSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    files = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.FileField())
    #files = serializers.ListField(child=FileSerializer())

    def create(self, validated_data):
        files = validated_data['files']
        file_objs = [File.objects.create(file=file) for file in files]
        return file_objs
```

**models.py**

```
class File(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def delete(self, *args, **kargs):
        self.file.delete()
        super().delete(*args, **kargs)
```

What is sent from my front-end :

[image]
Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because DRF uses same serializer to produce a response, so it tries to obtain `files` from the value, returned from the `create` method (it is a list). If you don't need to return the response actually, so you can set the field `files` as `write_only`:

```
class FilesSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    files = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.FileField(), write_only=True)
```

If you actually need some response (list of File objects), you need to overwrite the FileViewSet.create

```
 class FileViewSet():
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        response_serializer = FileSerializer(instance=serializer.instance, many=True)
        return Response(response_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: Alexandr, it works perfectly now, I've used your second solution and added the serilizer_class before the create def. 
Thanks again for the detailed answer.
Have a nice day